# Single character followed by an O is deleted using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

i need to match if a middle name is composed of
the following characters, “JO”, the O will be deleted, leaving behind the “J”. My regex is `standardName.replaceAll("(?<=[A-Z])[O]*", "")`. This is working but its replacing other strings too. For eg if i pass SOO BOO i am getting as S B only if i get a single character followed by O like above O should be replaced else not. Any suggestions?

Comment: `string.replace("JO", "J");` just replace if you have a `"JO"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
standardName.replaceAll("(?<=\\s[A-Z]|^[A-Z])[A-Z])[O]\\b", "")
```

This should do it for you.`\b` is a word boundary which will not allow a letter after first `O`.

or

```
standardName.replaceAll("(?<=\\s[A-Z]|^[A-Z])O(?=\\s|$)", "")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use word boundary on both sides:

```
standardName = standardName.replaceAll("(?<=\\b[A-Z])O\\b", "");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dT5gW8/1)

Answer (score 1):

You may try this,

```
standardName.replaceAll("(?<=\\s[A-Z])O(?!\\S)", "");
```

Following negative lookahead asserts that the `O` must not be followed by a non-space character.

or

```
standardName.replaceAll("\\s([A-Z])O\\s", "$1");
```